# Unable to use published KMP library due to error: Detecting cycle in external variants for

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

When I make a new KMP library (generated by Android Studio) and upload it to my private repo (using the maven-publish plugin), I am unable to use it in another KMP app because of an exception saying there are cyclic dependencies. I don't understand what's wrong because the library has zero dependencies.

When I publish a pure Java/JVM library then it works and I can use it in another Java app. So it seems to me the cause of this issue is in Kotlin Multiplatform? I've been stuck for ages so any help is appreciated.

**The full exception:**

Detecting cycle in external variants for :
my.group.id:my-artifact:0.0.1:
my.group.id.example:shared-module:1.0.0
Dependency resolution has ignored the cycle to produce a result. It is recommended to resolve the cycle by upgrading one or more dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was these lines:

```
publications.withType<MavenPublication> {
        artifactId = "annotations-kmp"
}
```

Changing the artifactId in this way caused kotlinMultiplatform publications to overwrite each other. The IDE can then still resolve the dependency making it look like it works. When running a Gradle build the KMP plugin will however check if the consumed dependency has sourcesets for all the sourcesets in the consumer. Because publications where overwritten, this is not the case and the build fails. The given exception is thus misleading unfortunately.

Comment: Is there a more correct way to set a custom artifact ID when using the maven publishing plugin to avoid this error? Having this issue as well for a project that depends on another artifact where I am setting the ID this way.

Comment: I haven't tried this myself but maybe you can append the type of sourceset to the custom name? There's some limited info here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mpp-publish-lib.html